# Restarting application using calling startActivity() but getting "complete action using"

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I want my application to restart when pressing "OK" in an alertDialog. But when I am pressing the button I am getting "Complete Action USing" screen, how do I start my application without having to go to "Complete Action.." ?

And is it the right way to restart application?

P.S. I need to restart application because initially when the application starts the list is shown from the local database, then after getting the new data from server and updating local database, I can't display updated list. It works after restarting app.

Code for calling startActivity:

```
Toast.makeText(mContext, "Reading complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        AlertDialog.Builder clickAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        clickAlert.setMessage("Database has been updated, please restart application to load new data. ");
        clickAlert.setPositiveButton("Restart", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                mContext.startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        clickAlert.create().show();
```

I have a listFragment that gets populated from a String adapter and this this string is filled from a method which returns data from server. I need to repopulate this list. 
Code:

```
// Get a cursor containing storelist

        Cursor curStoreList = mDbHelper.getStoreList();
        String[] StoreList = new String[curStoreList.getCount()];
        int i = 0;

        // Store returned items in StoreList[]
        while (curStoreList.moveToNext()) {
            String storeName = curStoreList.getString(0);
            StoreList[i] = storeName;
            i++;
        }

        // Create an adapter with list of stores and populate the list with
        // values
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, StoreList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
            mContext.startActivity(i);
```

change intent to

```
         Intent mainIntent = new Intent(your currentactivity.this, theclassyouwanttogo.class);
```

somthing like this setting the class instead of using explicit intent

Answer (score 0):

Why go through all the hassle of restarting the application. If you you use notifyDataChanged you can update your list( if you are talking about listview).

Comment: I think your problem is that your read your data before updating your database. First update your database and read it. Judging from your code you only update it when you want to restart the application. Not a good way!

Answer (score 0):

Than Lazy Ninja is right.
Try the following:

```
//1. Add a new Runnable
private Runnable updateAdapter = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();         
}
}; 
//2. Change your onClick to this:

@Override             
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {      
   runOnUiThread(updateAdapter);             
}
//3. Dont forget to set the adapter into your listcomponent:

setAdapter(adapter); 
setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

Comment: I have a listFragment that gets populated from a String adapter and this this string is filled from a method which returns data from server.